# How to set base line of inline-block element equal to the base line of its last child

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="horizontal">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>  

  <div class="vertical">
    <div>X</div>
    <div>Y</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.horizontal > div {
    display : inline-block;
}

.vertical > div {
    display : block;
}
```

Currently I have

```
    X
A B Y
```

But I want to have

```
A B X
    Y
```

I tried setting vertical-align: text-top, but it doesn't align in exact way, there are a couple of pixels missing which looks really ugly.

P.S. I have jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr8W4/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
.horizontal > div {
    display : inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

I exaggerated the font-size to illustrate the alignment.

See fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/FqEqh/